# Is there a way to make the auto increment field prefixed by 000?

Tags: auto-increment

Is there a way to make the auto increment field prefixed by 000? For example instead of making it run from the number '1' it should auto increment in this method '001' then 002 and so on?

Answer (score 3):

Leading zeroes are meaningless in a decimal integer.

You could display that however using `printf("%03d", id)` or equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, otherwise it wouldn't be a real integral type, it would be a string.

If you need that, you might want to use your language's formatting function(s) to display it with padding zeroes.